# Show progress in nautilus for custom script

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus

I'm using ubuntu 19.10 without any modifications and I got a couple scripts set up so I can execute them with the contextual right click menu.

The thing is, once they are going, they are completely silent, and I don't really know whether they are executing or how to interrupt them.

Is there anything I can add to my script so it shows a progress bar in the browser the same way copying a file or compressing a file does?

Comment: You have to modify these scripts. If they are shell script, you can try Zenity.